# "baby" % {"babe": "bebe"}. How could this be useful?

Tags: python

The following is a line in a method of a class in Django:

`url = self.success_url % self.object.__dict__`

Then I tried an example:

```
>>> "baby" % {"babe": "bebe"}
"baby"
```

How could this be useful?

Comment: Note that this is old-style string formatting, and it's use is discouraged in new code, instead use [the more powerful `str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Also, what did you expect your example to do?

Comment: Nothing : ), I didn't see how it could be useful. Also, thanks for the heads up for the new formatting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`%` in that case is being used for [String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). Because there are no `%`s in the word "baby", the word is not modified at all.

In your example of the variable `url`, `self.success_url` may be something like `"hello %s"` and `self.object.__dict__` may be `{"test": "three"}`. So simply, that will print:

```
hello {'test': 'three'}
```

Do note that if you ever plan on using something like this, you should be using `.format()`:

```
>>> d = {'baby':'bebe'}
>>> "hello {[baby]}".format(d)
'hello bebe'
```

Comment: +1 and even : if there's a `%(babe)s` in your string, then the `%(babe)s` will be replaced by... babe :)

PS : Damn you have edited your post while i was writing this one.

Comment: Why is using `{baby}` with `format()` better than `%(baby)s` and a `dict`?

Comment: @SeppoErviälä Because `%` should no longer be used. It was supposed to be scrapped with python 3 (iirc), but for some reason it remained.

Comment: @SeppoErviälä See my comment on the question itself, and the link therein. `str.format()` is more powerful, and functions are generally more useful than operators for this kind of thing (it's akin to `print` becoming `print()` in 3.x). It gives better syntax, and more power, readability and flexibility.

Comment: I prefer `printf` style formatting but will switch if I start getting deprecation warnings. I doubt that'll happen before Python 4.

Comment: @Haidro: Not all Python devs have been convinced that `.format()` is a better tool (I do think it is), so although the `%` formatting syntax was deprecated it has been undeprecated since. Unfortunately.

Comment: @SeppoErviälä: The `.format()` function supports custom `.__format__()` hooks on the formatted objects. There is also a `format()` function to apply a formatting specification to a single value (`format(1.342, '0.02f')` for example). More flexibility, more power.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how does that differ from `"%.2f" % 1.342`?

Comment: @SeppoErviälä: In that `format()` will check for a `.__format__()` method on the value first. `decimal.Decimal()` uses that feature, as does `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Pythons [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) like so:

```
print "%(foo)s is good" % {"foo": "bar"}

> bar is good
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is useless, but try:

```
"Hello, my name is %(babe)s" % { 'babe' : 'bebe'}
```

Answer (score 2):

url can use any of object instance properties:

```
class X(object):
    success_url = "http://goo.gl/%(x)s" 

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 13

    def get_url(self):
        return self.success_url % self.object.__dict__

>>> X().get_url()
'http://goo.gl/13'
```

One can modify these attributes

```
>>>  x = X()
>>>  x.x = 174
>>>  X().get_url()
'http://goo.gl/174'
```

So this is useful when url depends on instance attributes  (In my example) or instance `object` attributes (in your one) for example document fields or id, etc.